# Can you make this function more efficient? Thank you

Tags: python

I have a list of profane words that I compare against user input:
(using Django)

```
def check_profanity(string):
    if string is not None:
        import os
        import gzip
        profanity_list = staticfiles_storage.path('users/files/list.txt')
        try:
            with gzip.open(profanity_list) as f:
                profanity_lines = f.read().decode().splitlines()
        except IOError:
            with open(profanity_list) as f:
                profanity_lines = f.read().splitlines()
        profanity = {p for p in profanity_lines}
        words = string.split()
        for word in words:
            for bad_word in profanity:
                if bad_word in word:
                    return True
        return False
```

Thank you for any criticisms.

Comment: I would replace your loop with `return bool(set(profanity_lines).intersection(string.split()))`.

Comment: It looks like you're loading the profanity word list every time you check for profanity. Perhaps you should just do that once, and cache the list?

Comment: Stack overflow is for asking questions about specific problems. General optimizations might better fit in the code review stack exchange. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OlvinRoght That isn't 100% equivalent. For example, if you have the word `dog` in your profanity list, and a user types `doggy`, then the OP's solution will catch that, but yours wouldn't unless it was an exact match.

Comment: @NickODell, yes you're right, good to notice that, I've just guessed that equality test should fit from variable naming (imho, bad_**word** is a word).

Comment: @NickODell TYVM, what is an example of caching something like that? I don't know where to begin...

Comment: @NicholasPolino Split this into two functions. The first function loads the profanity list and returns it. The second calls the first function and checks the user input against the profanity list. Then, use the [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator to cache the output of the first function.

Comment: @DapperDuck Thanks for pointing that out, will do in the future.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Improve my code” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: @Prune Got it, honest mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move loading from file into a separate function and perform it once:

```py
def _read_file_lines(fn):
    with open(fn, "rb") as f:
        if f.read(2) == b"\x1f\x8b":  # magic
            from gzip import GzipFile
            _f = GzipFile(fileobj=f)
        else:
            _f = f

        _f.seek(0)  # move back to file beginning
        return set(_f.read().decode().splitlines())

profanity = _read_file_lines(staticfiles_storage.path("users/files/list.txt"))

def check_profanity(string):
    return string is not None and any(bad_word in string for bad_word in profanity)

# another option which should be slightly faster but will match only whole word

def check_profanity(string):
    return string is not None and profanity.intersection(string.split())
```

*P.S. Haven't tested it so write in comments if there's any issues with code, but there shouldn't be any.*

Comment: Will test shortly, definitely helpful for me and thank you.